# Rename Axis in rCharts

Tags: r, rename, axis, rcharts

How do I rename the yaxis name from Conference to New.

```
library(rCharts)
library(reshape2)
meansconferences=read.csv("https://raw.github.com/patilv/ESPNBball/master/meansconferences.csv")
meltmeansconferences=melt(meansconferences[-c(1,10:14)], id.vars=c("Conference","Year")) 
d1=dPlot(y="Conference", x="value",data=meltmeansconferences, groups="variable",type="bar")
d1$yAxis(type="addCategoryAxis",axisLabel = "new")
d1$xAxis(type="addPctAxis")
d1$legend(
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  width = 500,
  height = 75,
  horizontalAlign = "right"
)
d1
```

I try

```
d1$yAxis(type="addCategoryAxis",axisLabel = "new")
```

Not working.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing axis labels with dimple (that is, `dPlot()`) has been described here

[How to change the axis title with rCharts, dPlot and dimple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875447/how-to-change-the-axis-title-with-rcharts-dplot-and-dimple)